# Dismiss Dialog on hyperlink click to another activity

Tags: android, hyperlink, dialog

So i have a dialog that has a hyperlink like show below. When you click on it it opens up myacitivty over the current activity and the dialog box displaying over it.

```
"<a href=\"sherif-activity://myactivity?tag=" + s + "&id="+ id+ " \">" + s + "</a>" ;
```

My question is how do i close the dialog when i click the above hyperlink.